# Problem with pdfposter

Tags: pdf

Using PHP and TCPDF I create A3 portrait PDF document that I need to split in two A4 lanscape. So the top of the A3 must became page 1 of the A4 and the bottom of the A3 must became page 2.

As PHP+TCPDF seems not able to do that, I have installed pdfposter (6.0) and exec it from PHP. It works as the A4 page is created, but not the way I want.

I tried "pdfposter -m a4 -p 2x1a4" and "pdfposter -m a4 -p 1x2a4" but each time I get the result of the picture enclosed: left part is my A3 and right, the result I get which is not "really" what I'm waiting for...

I though my A3 was not corret but when I use online tools like the one at sejda.com I can split the A3 on two A4.

Any idea about the pdfposter command or maybe another tool? (I'm on Debian Jessie).

Edit: I tried also "pdfposter -s1" and get same wrong result...

[image]

Comment: (1) What do you mean by “my A3 was not correct”? (2) Wow, that result that you’re getting isn’t even *close* to what you want — or am I totally missing the point? (3) Are you saying that you can get the result you want from online tools like the one at sejda.com? (4) People seem to like [the PDF Toolkit, PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).  I’ve never used it, so I don’t know whether it will help you; you might want to check it out.

Comment: (1) I thought it was not. As it's a PDF I create on the fly. But i fact all software I've used are able to rad it without any problem. (2) You're right. Lol. (3) Yes. Using sedja.com I have exactly the result I want. (4). I'll have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found!
pdfposter you get when you just apt-get on Debian, is the stable version, 0.6
This version works perfectly with basic PDF. But in my case, the PDF is made using the rotation feature of PHP/TCPDF (the top bloc is rotated by 180° and the middle one by 90°). This **IS** the problem and the PDF I get is not compatible with pdfposter 0.6

To get better compatibility you need to install the last version from Git (pdfposter 0.7). And with this version, it works fine!